# Can I upgrade Windows Office Home to Office Professional?

Tags: upgrade, microsoft-office-2010

Can I upgrade Windows Office Home to Office Professional?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "upgrade" pricing and options for Microsoft Office.  However, with the new Office 2010, if you have purchased a suite, and wish to "upgrade" to a different one with more of the Office programs, you can individually purchase the programs that you wish to use from the [Microsoft online store](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Office-Office-2010-Stand-Alone-Programs/category/211).

Comment: How? Who do I contact? Where is the web site? How do I do it?

Comment: what version of office are you running?

Comment: after reading [this](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/clean_install_upgrade_media.asp) it appears that some people are successful and other aren't... like me.

Comment: Windows Office Home 2010